# How to group and combine two streams based on the first?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-cocoa

I want to group and combine two streams based on the values of the first. To illustrate with a specific example,

[image: Marbles]

Whenever the first stream changes, I want to combine values with the second stream but skipping the immediate next value (i.e. values 1, 3, and 6 in the diagram).

I'm using ReactiveCocoa on iOS but examples using other reactive frameworks are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, it would be something like (not tested though):

```
const result$ = a$.flatMapLatest(a => b.skip(1).map(b => {a,b}))
```

What this is supposed to do :

- for each incoming a, listen on bs, and skip the first b, and put together the b and the a

Constraints you have :

- b must be a hot stream

Nice diagram by the way.

Answer (score 1):

My current implementation in ReactiveCocoa:

```swift
var cook = MutableProperty("")
var ingredient = MutableProperty("")

cook.signal.observeNext { cook in
    print(">", cook)
}

let skipFirst = cook.signal
    .flatMap(.latest) { cookValue in
        return ingredient.signal
            .map { ingredientValue in
                "\(cookValue) \(ingredientValue)"
            }
            .skip(first: 1)
    }

skipFirst.observeNext { str in
    print(">>", str)
}

// Send values

cook.value = "grill"
ingredient.value = "asparagus"
ingredient.value = "beef"

cook.value = "fry"
ingredient.value = "ice cream"
ingredient.value = "donut"
ingredient.value = "shoe"

cook.value = "steam"
ingredient.value = "egg"
ingredient.value = "lettuce"
```

This prints:

```
> grill
>> grill beef
> fry
>> fry donut
>> fry shoe
> steam
>> steam lettuce
```

But this means that if I also want to use the first value of each group, I have to repeat the `flatMap` transformation, which doesn't seem very DRY.

```swift
cook.signal
    .flatMap(.latest) { cookValue in
        return ingredient.signal
            .map { ingredientValue in
                "\(cookValue) \(ingredientValue)"
            }
            .take(first: 1)
    }
    .observeNext { str in
        print("**>", str)
    }
```